# How to find the best min_samples for RANSACRegressor for non-linear estimator

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, ransac

I read the scikit-learn documentation about [RANSACRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RANSACRegressor.html). It says

> the min_samples parameter is highly dependent upon the model.

So, how one can calculate the `min_samples` parameter for non-linear estimator? For example, I want to use `SVR` with `rbf` kernel. What is the `min_sample` for this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot generalize a rule to have an approximate min_samples value. However, you can use some domain knowledge to get to a starting point. For example, if the relationship between the features and the target variable is highly nonlinear, then we can assume there might be quite some noise and will want a higher value of `min_samples`. Higher the value of `min_samples` we will need higher data points to be inliers before fitting the model. And the vice verse.

On the other hand, you can let the machine estimate it for you. Do a grid search of different values of `min_samples` during cross-validation and pick the one where the accuracy in both the training and validation set is highest.